# iostream sentry doesn't set failbit when it has reached the end

Tags: c++, stream, iostream

for the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    istringstream iss("a");
    iss.get();
    cout << iss.tellg() << endl;  // 1
    cout << iss.fail() << endl;   // 0
}
```

I'd expect the result be -1,1 not 1, 0.

`tellg` will first construct a `sentry` and then check `fail()`.

according to http://eel.is/c++draft/istream::sentry#2

> If is.rdbuf()->sbumpc() or is.rdbuf()->sgetc() returns
>   traits​::​eof(), the function calls setstate(failbit | eofbit) (which
>   may throw ios_­base​::​failure).

so `fail()` should be true, and `tellg` should return -1.

Comment: It seems very odd to me that `fail()` would return true after I ask the stream to read one character and it reads one character.

Comment: You could/should check the return value of `get` as well.

Answer (score 1):

From the ref of [`std::istream::tellg`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/tellg/):

> if member `fail` returns true, the function returns -1.

From the ref of [`std::ios::fail`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/):

> **Check whether either `failbit` or `badbit` is set**
>
> Returns true if either (or both) the failbit or the badbit error state flags is set for the stream.
>
> At least one of these flags is set when an error occurs during an
>   input operation.

Check with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    istringstream iss("a");
    iss.get();
    cout << iss.fail() << endl;   // 0
    cout << iss.tellg() << endl;  // 1
    cout << iss.eof() << endl;    // 0
}
```

Comment: so this becomes why the sentry doesn't correctly set the failbit | eofbit.

Comment: Yeah @FunkyBaby, if you want accept my answer BTW! :)